# Android Parsing JSON: Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, json

Hello everyone i have a problem in parsing this JSON file http://ammantimes.net/android/ammantimes.php?at_mod=news
Please help me to solve the problem:

Here's my code i use to parse it:

```
public String getJSONTextFromUrl(String url) {
        // initialize
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        // http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = URLDecoder.decode(sb.toString(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("JSON: = " + result);
        System.out.println("JSON SIZE: = " + result.length());

        // return result.replace(result.charAt(0), ' ');
        return result;
    }

public JSONObject getJSONFromScript(String jsonText) {

        JSONObject jObject = null;
        String result = getJSONTextFromUrl(jsonText);

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jObject;

    }
```

And here is the logcat output and error that i get:

```
04-10 14:48:25.070: I/System.out(28470): JSON: = {"news":[{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"}]}
04-10 14:48:25.070: I/System.out(28470): JSON SIZE: = 755


04-10 14:48:25.070: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=11) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(28470): (thUse=11) NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault()
04-10 14:48:25.070: E/log_tag(28470): Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: {"news":[{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"}]}
04-10 14:48:25.070: E/log_tag(28470): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException

04-10 14:48:25.070: I/System.out(28470): JSON Text: = 
04-10 14:48:25.070: I/System.out(28470): JSON Text SIZE: = 0

04-10 14:48:25.070: E/log_tag(28470): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-10 14:48:25.070: W/dalvikvm(28470): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
04-10 14:48:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28470): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
04-10 14:48:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28470): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 14:48:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28470):    at com.jordaneaucation.json.JSONParser.getNewsMap(JSONParser.java:59)
04-10 14:48:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28470):    at com.jordaneaucation.ui.NewsTab$1.run(NewsTab.java:72)
04-10 14:48:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(28470):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470): Activity com.jordaneaucation.ui.NewsTab has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40530778 that was originally added here
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.jordaneaucation.ui.NewsTab has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40530778 that was originally added here
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:273)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:174)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:117)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at com.jordaneaucation.ui.NewsTab.onCreate(NewsTab.java:44)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
04-10 14:48:31.570: E/WindowManager(28470):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the printStackTrace()

```
04-10 15:09:58.189: W/System.err(28947): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-10 15:09:58.189: W/System.err(28947):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
04-10 15:09:58.189: W/System.err(28947):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:93)
04-10 15:09:58.189: W/System.err(28947):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
04-10 15:09:58.189: W/System.err(28947):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
04-10 15:09:58.189: W/System.err(28947):    at com.jordaneaucation.json.JSONParser.getJSONFromScript(JSONParser.java:131)
04-10 15:09:58.189: W/System.err(28947):    at com.jordaneaucation.json.JSONParser.getNewsMap(JSONParser.java:54)
04-10 15:09:58.189: W/System.err(28947):    at com.jordaneaucation.ui.NewsTab$1.run(NewsTab.java:72)
04-10 15:09:58.189: W/System.err(28947):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-10 15:09:58.189: W/dalvikvm(28947): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
```

Comment: -1 for catching the exception without a printstacktrace in it.

Comment: also, the error clearly is not with parsing the json, as it crashes way before reaching that part

Comment: @njzk2 I added the print stack trace

Comment: no, you didn't. this happens long after the initial error has happened. replace `Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());` by `e.printStackTrace()` and post the result

Answer (score 0):

i normally use GSON to parse JSON data..

You can refer 
[parsing array in gson in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301882/parsing-array-in-gson-in-java)

GSON library you can get from 
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

add these google jar files in your project

To parse JSON, use code like:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), charset);

WebsiteResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, WebsiteResults.class);
```

WebsiteResults is the class you will create to parse JSON like mentioned in link.

Comment: well i asking him to use different approach, main aim is to parse the JSON response, i am just suggesting alternate solution if this problem can't be solved...

Comment: the problem is in the url. your suggested modification is after the error has taken place, meaning it will still not work.

Comment: thank you all @njzk2 and (Gaurav), the main problem was in the HTTPClient and response and i solve it by using commons-httpclient library + recieved text was containing invalid characters and the problem was solved by removing them : result = result.substring(3, x);

Answer (score 0):

Read your logs.

This is your error:

`04-10 14:48:25.070: E/log_tag(28470): Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: {"news":[{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"},{"NewsID":"aa","StatusID":"aa","NewsSubject":"aa","NewsTitle":"aa","NewsPhoto":"aa","IsDeleted":"aa","SubmitDateTime":"aa"}]}`

You are mistaking the url and the post parameters. In new HttpPost(url), your url is actually this long json string. (`jsonText` from the calling method).

The rest of your errors comes from the fact that you don't act on the first error. Your request is not executed, `is` stays null, hence the NPE after that, result stays empty, your JSONObject is unhappy with the empty parameter, result stays null, hence the final NPE.

This is a typical case of "i don't care about exceptions", resulting in propagating an error far from its origin. Don't ignore exception. Don't continue a treatment on a result from an Http connection if the connection fails (!)

Comment: Thank you , i solved the problem by using commons-httpclient library,,, GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(url);
   getMethod.setDoAuthentication(true);